# Android base64 string as image

Tags: java, android, image, base64, android-webview

I have a problem with downloading images using webview. I use `HitTestResult` to detect the type of item clicked and then I use `DownloadManager` to download images from url. But it works fine only with `HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE`, but with `HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE` I get something like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD...very long string.`
I tried to use `Base64.decode()` and create `Bitmap` and then save it to storage, but it didnt work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use decode like this:

```
    String encodedString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
    encodedString = encodedString.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
    byte[] image = Base64.decode(encodedString.getBytes(), 0);




    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, image.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot!!